# What is the proper connection string when using FbClient for FirebirdSql

Tags: c#, firebird, firebird2.5

The way I understand it, FbClient uses the ADO.NET to make the db connection.  ADO.NET optimizes connection pooling.  With that in mind, should I set the Pooling option = true in the connection string or should I leave it blank.  Below are two connection strings, which one would be better to use with FbClient?

```
connectionString="User=******;Password=********;Database=CBT;DataSource=localhost;Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=UTF8;Role=;Connection lifetime=15;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;"
```

or

```
connectionString="User=******;Password=********;Database=CBT;DataSource=localhost;Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=UTF8;Role=;Connection lifetime=15;"
```

Comment: ADO.net itself doesn't do pooling, that is handled by the individual client implementations. Pooling is enabled by default for the Firebird .NET provider.

Comment: So I don't need to set the pooling options in the connection string?

Comment: You only need to set the options if you want to modify the defaults or if you want to be explicit in your config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to enable pooling explicitly, because it is enabled by default.

See: https://github.com/cincuranet/NETProvider/blob/master/NETProvider/source/FirebirdSql/Data/FirebirdClient/FbConnectionString.cs#L376

```
private void SetDefaultOptions()
{
    if (this.options == null)
    {
        this.options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    this.options.Clear();

    // Add default key pairs values
    /* ... */
    this.options.Add("pooling", true);
    this.options.Add("connection lifetime", 0);
    this.options.Add("min pool size", 0);
    this.options.Add("max pool size", 100);
    this.options.Add("connection timeout", 15);
    /* ... */
}
```